# Fastest way to cross check 2 Lists with eachother

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist

What would be the most effective method to check whether a string value from list1 exists in list2?

Pseudo Code example

```
StringList List1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
StringList List2 = {"d", "c", "b", "a"};

foreach (string a in List1)
{
    foreach (string b in List2)
    {
        if(a==b)
        {
             WriteLine("match");
        }
    }
}
```

This method is far too slow to be the best solution, the platform I am using is BI#, a derivative off C#. Array.Exists does not exist in this current library.

Comment: Sorting first or making a lookup table often lets you get speedup over quadratic algos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Intersect`:

```
var allIntersections = List1.Intersect(List2);

foreach(string match in allIntersections)
   Console.WriteLine(match);
```

If you just want to know if at least one intersects:

```
bool anyExist = allIntersections.Any();
```

Comment: Though 'Intersect' doesn't exist in this library you've given me a very valid idea, I'll post an answer tell me what you think

Comment: @ArraysRus: you have to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your classs file

Comment: @ArraysRus: do you have `HashSet<T>`?

Comment: I can't add any library's its not a standard C# platform, and no I don't have `HashSet<T>`

Comment: This would be the correct answer for a standard C# platform, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Converting the List into a comma deliminated string, allows to use a standard `InString` function in this case a function called `StringContains`;

```
 foreach (string a in List1)
{
    if(StringContains(a, NewString))
    {
        WriteLine("Match");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting to see how much faster this is, than using a double loop. Also, choose your deliminator wisely :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool flag= list2.Except(list1).Any();
```

This will be true if list1 doesn't contains all from list2.